# The distribution for a function of Binomially distributed variables with different probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

If (X_1,...,X_m) ~ Bernoulli(p) and (Y_1,...Y_n) ~ Bernoulli(1-p), how should I go about finding the distribution for the statistic T = (Sum of X's) - (Sum of Y's) when X and Y are distributed independently??? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $Y\sim\operatorname{Bernoulli}(1-p)$ then $1-Y\sim\operatorname{Bernoulli}(p).$

So
\begin{align}
& \sum_{i=1}^m X_i - \sum_{j=1}^n Y_i \\[10pt]
= {} & \sum_{i=1}^m X_i + \sum_{j=1}^n (1-Y_i) - \sum_{j=1}^n 1 \\[10pt]
= {} & \Big[ \text{the sum of $m+n$ indepedent Bernoulli$(p)$ random variables} \Big] - n.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ is $\mbox{Bin}(n,p)$. $\sum_{i=1}^mY_i$ is $\mbox{Bin}(m,1-p)=m-\mbox{Bin}(m,p)$. Then

$$\sum_{i=1}^nX_i-\sum_{i=1}^nY_i=\mbox{Bin}(m,p)+\mbox{Bin}(m,p)-m=\mbox{Bin}(2m,p)-m,$$

where the equalities are in distribution.

Comment: What does it mean to say that Bin(m, 1-p) = m - Bin(m, p)? Are you able to add and subtract numbers to a distribution? Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: The equality is in distribution. To see this, let $Z_i=1-X_i$ and notice that $\sum_{i=1}^nZ_i$ is distributed like $n-\mbox{Bin}(n,p)$. On the other hand $Z_i=\mbox{Ber}(1-p)$.

Comment: Got it now. Thanks!!